# Isosceles triangle with integer side $p, p, p+q$ - What is the flaw in this logic?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

[image]

Let
$$AB=BD=AE=p$$
$$AD=DE=q$$
$$\angle ABC=\theta$$
$$\angle CAD=\alpha$$
$$\angle ACB=ACD=90°$$

Let $p>q,\implies \theta>0,\ \alpha>0$.

Using the law of sines,

In $\triangle ADE$:

$$\frac{q}{\sin\left(\theta\right)}={p \over \sin(90°+α)}$$

In $\triangle ABE$:

$$\frac{p}{\sin\left(\theta\right)}={p+q \over \sin(90°+α)}$$

We get the ratio
$$\frac{q}{p}=\frac{p}{p+q}$$
$$\implies q\left(p+q\right)=p^2$$
$$\implies pq+q^2=p^2$$
$$\implies pq=p^2-q^2=\left(p-q\right)\left(p+q\right)$$

This equation has no solutions in integers $p,q$ except $p=q=0$ but we can construct a triangle with $p,q$ integers. For eg:

[image]

What is the flaw in the logic? Is it due to the fact that there is a $\sin(90° + \alpha)$ in the denominator that we have cancelled out and it can take values of $0$ for some values of $90° + \alpha$?

I am trying to derive the condition for an isosceles triangle with integer sides, $p, p, p+q$.

Comment: There is something wrong in the drawing... the solution 5-5-8 means that AC=3=q. But we cannot have both AC=3 and AD=3

Comment: Note that $\theta=36^\circ$，unless you abandon $AD=DE$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flaw is at "Let".

According to your diagram, since $BA = BD = p$:

$$90^\circ -\theta+\alpha = 90^\circ -\alpha$$

By considering the exterior angle of $\triangle ADE$:

$$90^\circ - \alpha = 2\theta$$

We can in fact solve the two equations to obtain:

$$\alpha = 18^\circ, \ \theta = 36^\circ$$

Which, of course, has no solutions in the integers, because it is related to the golden ratio.

For your $5-5-8$ triangle, we don't have the $q$ defined equal. We should have $q=3$, but the altitude is also $3$, so it does not satisfy the conditions in "Let".

Comment: Hmm, looks like a nice way to confuse everyone with this flaw.